# Exclude option vs. Entry Point in Webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, config

If you have an entry point in Webpack, doesn't that mean Webpack will only bundle up and transform the files that are in that entry point or `require`d by that entry point? That would then automatically negate or exclude the files that aren't `require`d by that entry point file, correct? Why do you still need an exclude option in the loader config for the files in your `node_modules`? That isn't `require`d in your entry point so I thought webpack would ignore those files altogether, or is there some magic I'm missing? If you don't have the exclude option, will loaders automatically just try to transform **all** your files in your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules do not include any files, but they apply the loader(s) to any imported module that satisfies the condition. The `exclude` option on a rule only decides whether an already imported file should be processed by the loader(s).

The `node_modules` are commonly excluded from a `.js` rule, because there is usually no reason to transform them, as most packages are already transpiled before they are being published. Having to process the whole `node_modules` that you're using, will increase the build time by quite a bit, even if it's just one loader, at the very least it has to parse the module and return a valid module, which already takes some time.

There are other purposes for the `exclude` and `include` options. For example you could decide to use [CSS modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules) for your project but you have some third party library that depends on having regular (global) CSS and you can't easily change the code that uses the CSS. You could define the following rules:

```
{
  // For all .css files except the ones in 3rd-party-lib
  test: /\.css$/,
  exclude: /3rd-party-lib/,
  use: [
    'style-loader',
    { loader: 'css-loader', options: { modules: true } }
  ]
},
{
  // For all .css files in 3rd-party-lib
  test: /\.css$/,
  include: /3rd-party-lib/,
  use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
}
```

This could be anything from changing one option to using a totally different set of loaders, even though it might be same the file type.

Comment: so you never have to exclude anything inside your node_modules because they'll never be included in your loaders anyway right?

Comment: You do need to exclude them if you don't want them to be processed by the loaders. Everything you import will be tested against the rules. It's just the modules that you don't import, are not included by webpack in the first place. But it's perfectly possible that you don't want to apply some loaders to a file that you include. For example when you use `react` (which will be `node_modules/react`), you don't need to transpile it with babel, therefore you can exclude it, and likewise for other `node_modules`.